# postfix/smtpd lost connection after AUTH from <server>[ip]

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, ubuntu-14.04

I try to send mail from a private LAN server to my private postfix server and I get this error, but I can't find its meanning:

```
# /var/log/mail.log

Jul  8 15:02:50 mail-srv postfix/smtpd[18222]: connect from <server>[ip]
Jul  8 15:02:50 mail-srv postfix/smtpd[18222]: lost connection after AUTH from <server>[ip]
Jul  8 15:02:50 mail-srv postfix/smtpd[18222]: disconnect from <server>[ip]
```

I found results about spam or postfix brut attacks but here it is my own server that try to send mails.

I added it VLAN to `my_networks` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

My postfix server run on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Check the computer that own that IP address... Find out what's program that connect to your server

Comment: I know that. Its mine. I installed gitlab on a server and try to configure smtp

Comment: Well, try to inspect gitlab log to find out why gitlab SMTP client disconnected after AUTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

This error means that the mail client close the connection after trying to auth.

Indeed, the solution is to inspect if the client auth configuration correctly match the postfix server auth configuration.

In my case, postfix didn't enable authentication so I disabled authentication client-side and it worked.

Question: why to downvote my question ? Is there a problem with it ?

Comment: In client-server architecture like SMTP, if something was wrong then you need to checks **both** client and server. Perhaps the downvoter thinks that you lacks this *basic* troubleshooting step in your question above. *diclaimer: I'm not the downvoter*

Comment: You're probably right, but hey, its the point. It can be basic but its a question so... Never mind. Thanks to you.